# Windows 10 Mail starts then immediately closes

Tags: windows-10, email

I have Win 10 Pro 64-bit (Build 11082).
When I run Mail, it opens but then immediately closes.

I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it.  I ran sfc /scannow (no corrupted files detected) and I even tried running it from a different user account. It does the same thing in all user accounts.

How can I get Mail to run?

Comment: Why are you running an Insider Preview build?  Anyways do you have UAC enabled?

Comment: Check event log

Comment: I'm running an Insider Preview because it's my job to keep up on the latest versions (including betas) of software. I do have UAC enabled.

Comment: Is there an error for the app in event viewer we could take a look at? You could aslo try typing in "wsreset"  in the Run Window Windows key + R. Ive heard of location messing with this application also.

Answer (score 0):

when u do the following it works for a little while. then microsoft somehow screws it up again with its wonderful screwup updates that you cannot reasonably disable.

dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
sfc /scannow